# Different ways to avoid naming conflicts with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I can see there are many ways to use jQuery safely in the javascript code. That means that the typical '$' shortcut for jQuery doesn't work, so it doesn't conflict with any other JavaScript libraries.

1. We can create no conflict object.

   ```
   var j = jQuery.noConflict();
   // Do something with jQuery
   j("div p").hide();
   ```
2. Using jQuery instead on $ in the code.

   ```
   jQuery("div p").hide();
   ```
3. Using Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) something like this.

   ```
   (function($) {
       $("div p").hide();
   })( jQuery );
   ```

**So which will be the best method to use?** Or is there a better method not listed?

Thanks in advance...!!

Comment: The safest way is to use nothing but jQuery.

Comment: Huh. The code selection-thing isn't working...

Comment: @BoltClock is this really what he asked for?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Are you facing any error message with one of the approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good practice/habit  to use **jQuery** instead of **$**. So the ideal way would be method 2. **$** is just a shorthand for the word **jQuery**. Although you can use any of the 3,  all three are equally okay

Answer (score 4):

Use method 2. Just call it with *JQuery*. Because **no other library will call themself JQuery.**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the third option, mainly because :

- it automatically avoids conflict with other libraries (and you don't have to rely on the `noConflict` method - thus this way of coding can be applied to any libraries)
- it prevents you from polluting the global namespace (of course, if you do not pin variables directly to the window : `window.foo = bar`)
- you can still use the dollar sign instead of the big *jQuery* word (which in development you tend to use at least 30 times on a small project)

Comment: 3rd method is actually method 2 with closure.

Comment: yes, and you can combine the first and last too : `(function($){})(jQuery.noConflict())`